# npm install fails on a vagrant VM with debian 7.8 and postgres 9.3

Tags: node.js, npm, debian, vagrant, postgresql-9.3

I need to reproduce a production node environment with specific (old) versions, on my local mac machine using vagrant, and when i run `npm install` it always fails with errors as follow:

- optional dep failed continuing fsevents@0.3.6
- optional dep failed, continuing readable-stream@1.1.13
- optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-xx
- EEXIST, open '/root/.npm/0ae333bd-t-npm-inherits-2-0-1-package-tgz.lock'
  File exists: /root/.npm/0ae333bd-t-npm-inherits-2-0-1-package-tgz.lock
  Move it away, and try again.

I have tried many things without success:

- npm install --no-bin-links
- sudo npm install
- npm cache clean
- rm -r node_modules
- rm -r /root/.npm/

I could not figure out what I am doing wrong and what's the cause...

Any idea about what I am doing wrong or some suggestions would be welcome. Thanks.

**Here is my env details:**

- OS: Debian 7.8
- node: v0.10.36
- npm: 1.4.28
- PostgreSql : 9.3.6
- PostGis: 2.1
- git:1.7.10.4
- ruby: 1.9.3

I have 2 directories in my vagrant project:

- www: containes my app
- config: containes packages list and db dump

My vagrant  file:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/debian-7.8-64-puppet"
    config.vm.hostname = "ppld-preprod"
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh"

    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8999

    config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", disabled: true
    config.vm.synced_folder "www", "/vagrant/www"
    config.vm.synced_folder "config", "/vagrant/config"
end
```

My provision file:

```
apt-get -y update

dpkg --set-selections < /config/packages_list
apt-get -y -u dselect-upgrade

wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.36/node-v0.10.36.tar.gz
tar xfz node-v0.10.36.tar.gz
cd node-v0.10.36
./configure
make    

make install

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ wheezy-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'

sudo apt-get -y install wget ca-certificates
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

apt-get -y update

sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-server-dev-9.3

sudo apt-get -y install git

sudo chown -R $(whoami) "/vagrant/"
sudo chmod -R 777 /vagrant/

cd /vagrant/www/ppld/
sudo npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is really strange, can you update your npm to version 2+ ?

`npm update -g npm`

Comment: I cannot update npm actually... Well i can do it to check if it resolves the problem, but the idea was to have an environment identical to the production, and the app is running fine on production

Comment: For your problem, i only see a corrupted cache that you emptied or 2 npm running at the same time. NPM corrected a bunch of issues in v2, and as it's only used during installation process, that won't have any effect on your tests.
Are you using a shrinkwrap ?

Comment: No, I am not using shrinkwrap... You were right, `npm update` does resolve the problem (it update npm to 2.11.1). I will try again using npm version 1.4.28 and check if 2 npm are running

Comment: If you want the exact same environment as your production, you should use shrinkwrap because your dependencies and subdependencies wont be the same on both environment.